# Как выполнить заново саб-транзакцию внутри serializable транзакции?

Tags: sql, postgresql, serializable

В своем приложении я использую транзакции PostgreSQL с уровнем изоляции SERIALIZABLE и вложенные сейвпоинты (я называю их саб-транзакциями). Иногда транзакции или саб-транзакции не проходят из-за ошибок сериализации и тогда я пытаюсь повторить действия, выполнявшиеся внутри них.

Прооблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь повторить действия из саб-транзакции (откатиться до последнего сейвпоинта, создать новый сейвпоинт и выполнить действия снова), postgresql не видит изменений, внесенных в других потоках, и поэтому все последующие попытки валятся по такой же ошибке сериализации.

Для ясности приведу простой пример (несколько урезанный по сравнению с реальными действиями, но достаточный для воспроизведения сути проблемы). В первом потоке:

```
create table if not exists test(id int);
truncate test;

begin;
set isolation level serializable;

savepoint p1;
select id from test where id = 1;
# тут могут быть любые запросы, приводящие к ошибке сериализации
rollback to p1;
```

Во втором потоке:

```
insert into test(id) values (1);
```

В первом потоке:

```
savepoint p2;
select id from test where id = 1;
```

Последний SELECT не видит строку, вставленную в другом потоке, и отдаёт "0 строк". Насколько я понимаю, после выполнения первого SELECT'а postgresql игнорирует любые внешние изменения, которые могут изменить его результаты. Но я не хочу игнорировать их. Я хочу забыть обо всём, что происходило внутри отменённой саб-транзакции и жить дальше. И я не хочу перевыполнять всю транзакцию из-за ошибки в мелкой саб-транзакции.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ продолжить выполнение транзакции с учетом изменений, внесенных в других потоках?

Comment: Как видно что во втором потоке Insert выполняется до select из savepoint 2 первого потока? При уровне 'SERIALIZABLE' транзакции вроде выполняются по-очереди. Пока первый не закончится, второй и не запуститься.

Comment: У postgres ещё есть одна особенность. Если случилась ошибка в транзакции, то закоммитить её уже не возможно. Можно только откатиться до последней удачной точки. А после начать новую транзакцию.

Comment: @Sergey Как видно, в каком порядке? Открыл две консольки с postgresql и выполнил действия в интересующем меня порядке. А в тестах открыл два независимых подключения к БД.

Comment: По поводу второго сообщения - я так и делаю. Откатываюсь до последнего сейвпоинта.

Comment: Как бы то ни было, но SERIALIZABLE в любом случае и не должен видеть изменения, внесённые другими транзакциями. Результат `select id from test where id = 1;` в `savepoint p2` не должен отличаться от результата в `savepoint p1`

Comment: @Sergey нет, должен. И видит. Воспроизведение - выполнить действия из примера, исключив из него всё, что происходило внутри сейвпоинта p1. То есть, сначала начать транзакцию в потоке 1, затем вставить строки в потоке 2, затем выполнить select в потоке 1. В таком случае внешние изменения "подтягиваются", т.к. они не мешают сериализации.

Comment: Вот так определяется фантомное чтение, которого не должно быть при serializable в руководстве к postgres "`phantom read -
A transaction re-executes a query returning a set of rows that satisfy a search condition and finds that the set of rows satisfying the condition has changed due to another recently-committed transaction.`" Налицо повторное выполнение запроса из p1 в p2. Если один раз выполнить, то может быть и увидит. Но второе выполнение должно увидеть то же самое, что и в первый раз, что бы там не произошло в других потоках

Comment: Я это понимаю. Просто я ожидал, что запросы, выполненные внутри отмененной саб-транзакции, не будут при этом учитываться. Вопрос, собственно, и состоит в том, можно ли сделать так, чтоб они не учитывались. Использовать на проекте repeatable read, увы, тоже не вариант.

Comment: Может ошиблись, может нет? Чтобы видеть изменения других транзакций, надо `read commited`. `repeatable read` читает так же как `serializable` (точнее наоборот srializable как repeatable)

Comment: В postgres кстати есть система блокировок `postgres advisory lock`, которая может сильно упростить задачу, если трудно разобраться со стандартными блокировками sql. Легко тот же `read commited` "сериализовать" в нужный момент.